# Difference between polynomial embedding and canonical embedding

Tags: lwe, ring-lwe

Can anyone tell me the difference between working in the polynomial embedding for $R$-LWE, and working in the canonical embedding?

Comment: Each one is just a linear transform, or change of basis, of the other: if a ring element is vector $v$ in the polynomial embedding, then it is $\Sigma v$ on the canonical embedding, for a certain matrix $\Sigma$. The key nice thing about the canonical embedding is that both addition and multiplication in the ring are coordinate-wise in the embedding.

Comment: By "polynomial embedding" do you mean representing a polynomial by its vector of coefficients?

Comment: Yes, specifically, the coefficient vector of the polynomial residue (remainder) modulo the polynomial defining the ring.